# Seperate datasource for jobrepository and writer of Spring Batch

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch, spring-boot

Job is simple CSVtoDBFileWriter :

1. read CSV fileName and location from oracle1
2. read CSV file(batchreader)
3. write(batch writer) in tables(oracle2)

I have 2 datasource :

- **Oracle1**

  ```
        : available when application context loads and 
        : I read properties from Oracle1's tables to create oracle2
        : jobRepository related tables should be stored here(oracle1)
  ```
- **Oracle2** : Destination database where Spring batch's writer will finally output.

Question1 : Do I need XA transactionManager?

Question2 : Can I run this application in production only using Spring Boot, are there challanges with Spring Boot in production?

Comment: I am able to get this working by putting oracle2 datasource directly in writer as follows itemWriter.setDataSource(destinationDataSource());                  Is it using any transaction manager now?  Is it same as used by oracle1 datasource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need XA transaction when SB metadata tables are stored in a different database than the one using for data writing because checkpoint (data and SB metadata) must be stored at the same time to take care of synchronization and restartability.
Reading can be done from a different datasource without problems because reading is unrelated respect to where SB metadata are saved.

Comment: Thanks. So can I also have Reder(oracle1,oracle2,ftp,sftp) and Writer(oracle1,oracle2,ftp,sftp) dynamically pick up datasources? So one one job but reader and writer dynamically chossing peremutaion-combination of endpoints as mentioned above?

Comment: SB needs a DB datasource to store metadata. If your writer involves a different DB datasource you need XA.

Comment: Sure I agree to that. Other question is should I write seperate jobs for combinations of readers and writer or can I write a single job whose readers and writers can be injected dynamically.

Comment: Now I can't help you,sorry. Open a new question because I think this new one request a more elaborated answer then a comment