# Tasklet or ItemReader that makes calls to Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud

I'm attempting to create a Spring Batch tasklet that calls a `DatastoreRepository`.  Tasklet execute step

```
@Override public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext)
  throws Exception {

String syncId = this.stepExecutionContext.getJobParameters()
    .getString(JobParameterKeys.SYNC_ID);

SyncJob syncJob = syncJobRepo.findById(Long.parseLong(syncId)).get();
```

When I attempt to call the syncJobRepo I receive a the `org.springframework.transaction.NoTransactionException: No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope` exception.

I have a custom configured datasource (mySql instance) backing Spring Batch for storing the job execution metadata.

I've attempted to define the `DatastoreTransactionManager`

```
@Bean
DatastoreTransactionManager datastoreTransactionManager() {
DatastoreTransactionManager manager
    = new DatastoreTransactionManager(DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService());
return manager;
```

}

My configuration is annotated with `@EnableBatchProcessing`

the batch job config:

```
 @Bean public Job customersJob(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
  JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
  Tasklet batchCustomerReader,
  SyncJobNotificationListener listener,
  DatastoreTransactionManager datastoreTransactionManager) {

Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get(CUSTOMERS_BATCH_JOB_LOAD_FROM_ERP_STEP)
    .tasklet(batchCustomerReader)
    .transactionManager(datastoreTransactionManager)
    .listener(listener)
    .build();

return jobBuilderFactory.get(CUSTOMERS_BATCH_JOB)
    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
    .start(step)
    .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a custom configured datasource (mySql instance) backing Spring Batch for storing the job execution metadata.

If you use different datasources for Spring Batch meta-data and your business data, then you need to configure an XA transaction manager to synchronize the transaction between both datasources. This way, both data and meta-data are kept in sync in case of failure/restart scenario.

A similar Q/A can be found here: [Seperate datasource for jobrepository and writer of Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820818/seperate-datasource-for-jobrepository-and-writer-of-spring-batch)